# Building association between two tables before inserting

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have tables user_profile and roles.There exit a foreign key column roles_id in user_profile referencing roles table.
I have to build_association between both tables before inserting the data into user_profile table.

I am trying to do it using Ecto.Multi.merge but there are some errors. It is not working.And i dnt knw where i am commiting mistake.
According to me Ecto.Multi.merge function takes the multi object returned from function. 
Passing function directly is not working.

```
 def create_user_profile(profile_info, dealer_id) do
    import Sage
    client_id = Map.get(profile_info, "client_id")
    type = Map.get(profile_info, "user_type")
    role_name = Map.get(profile_info, "role_name")
    role_struct = Repo.get_by(Roles, role_name: role_name)

    Ecto.Multi.merge(Repo.get_by(Roles, role_name: role_name), fn %{role: role}->
    user_role = Ecto.build_assoc(role, :user_profile)|> UserProfile.changeset(profile_info)
    Ecto.Multi.new()
    |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:user_role, user_role)end)
    |> Ecto.Multi.merge(fn %{user: user} ->
      bank_detail =
        Ecto.build_assoc(user, :bank_details)
        |> BankDetails.changeset(profile_info)

      Ecto.Multi.new()
      |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:bank_detail, bank_detail)
    end)
```

here is a snippet of code. please help me. I am new to this language

whenever i try to run this using postman ...this error is displayed

```
(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Multi.merge/2
        (ecto) lib/ecto/multi.ex:228: Ecto.Multi.merge(%Accreditor.Role.Roles{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "roles">, id: 1, inserted_at: ~N[2019-05-31 07:21:21], permissions: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :permissions is not loaded>, role_name: "SUPER", updated_at: ~N[2019-05-31 07:21:21], user_profile: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user_profile is not loaded>, user_type: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user_type is not loaded>, user_type_id: 1}, #Function<3.131196970/1 in Accreditor.Accounts.create_user_profile/2>)
        (accreditor) lib/core/accounts/accounts.ex:224: Accreditor.Accounts.create_user_profile/2
        (accreditor) lib/core/accounts/accounts.ex:195: Accreditor.Accounts.create_account/2
        (accreditor) lib/web/controllers/user_controller.ex:17: AccreditorWeb.UserController.create_user/2
        (accreditor) lib/web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: AccreditorWeb.UserController.action/2
        (accreditor) lib/web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: AccreditorWeb.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (primus_web) lib/primus_web/endpoint.ex:1: PrimusWeb.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:275: Phoenix.Router.__call__/1
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router/route.ex:39: Phoenix.Router.Route.call/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:275: Phoenix.Router.__call__/1
        (primus_web) lib/primus_web/endpoint.ex:1: PrimusWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (primus_web) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: PrimusWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (primus_web) lib/primus_web/endpoint.ex:1: PrimusWeb.Endpoint.call/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:33: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/2
```

Comment: Please format the code so that it was readable _and_ post the full error message.

Comment: can you check now

Answer (score 2):

As it might be seen from the error message, `Repo.get_by/2` returns `%Accreditor.Role.Roles{}` struct, which has no `role` field. And you are trying to pass it to the function accepting a parameter that is to be pattern matched on `%{role: role}` which obviously fails.

```
Ecto.Multi.merge(%Accreditor.Role.Roles{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "roles">,
  id: 1,
  inserted_at: ~N[2019-05-31 07:21:21],
  permissions: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<[...]>,
  role_name: "SUPER",
  updated_at: ~N[2019-05-31 07:21:21],
  user_profile: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<[...]>,
  user_type: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<[...]>,
  user_type_id: 1}, #Function[...]}
```

You have not posted your schemas so I could only wild guess that your `Roles` schema has a way to get to `role` and somewhat like

```
roles = Repo.get_by(Roles, role_name: role_name)
Ecto.Multi.merge(get_role(roles), fn role -> ... end)
```

would fix the issue.

Comment: ```elixir roles = Repo.get_by(Roles, role_name: role_name)``` will return a struct having role_name in it. why to write another function ```elixir get_role``` in ```elixir Ecto.Multi.merge()```?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If you need the `role_name`, just update your function with `fn %{role_name: role_name} -> ` or whatever to indeed pattern match the result of `Repo.get_by/2`.